# Can I use the native animation driver to track a pan gesture?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

The React-Native Animated docs show this example as a way to make an Animated.Value (_panX) track a pan gesture:

```
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
   null,                // raw event arg ignored
   {dx: this._panX},    // gestureState arg
]),
```

Likewise, the Animated.event docs say I can pass a second config parameter, with:

> useNativeDriver: Uses the native driver when true. Default false.

Unfortunately, doing this appears to be broken:

```
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(..., { useNativeDriver: true });
```

In particular, because `PanResponder.create` has a `onResponderMove` function that does:

```
if (config.onPanResponderMove) {
  config.onPanResponderMove(e, gestureState);
}
```

Which causes an error, when it treats `config.onPanResponderMove` as a function, when it's actually an object...

Am I doing something wrong? Or is `useNativeDriver` not supported when making `Animated.Value` track a gesture? Would be nice to have something seamlessly track the mouse like that...

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? You can use `onPanResponderMove:() => { Animated.event(..., { useNativeDriver: true })};` which makes this a function, but then it evaluates only after you release press and jumps to new animated location, which is something I had a problem whit.